# autocorrelation function of time series data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, correlation

I have been trying to calculate an autocorrelation function, as defined in [statistical mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29), using numpy. Most of the documentation I found is relative to functions like [correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) and [convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve). However, for a given random variable x these functions just seem to calculate the sum

```
ACF(dt) = sum_{t=0}^T [(x(t)*x(t+dt)]
```

instead of the average

```
ACF(dt) = mean[x(t)*x(t+dt)]
```

so in fact for calculating an autocorrelation function one would need to do something like:

```
acf = np.correlate(x,x,mode='full')
acf_half = acf[acf.size / 2:]
ldata = len(acf)
acf = np.array([x/(ldata-i) for i,x in enumerate(acf_half)])
```

Of course we would need to subtract mean(x)**2 from the resulting acf to be correct.

Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the autocorrelation, correlation, etc. is the sum (integral).  Sometimes it is normalized, but not averaged in the sense as you've written above.  This is because they are defined in terms of the [mathematical convolution operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), which is simply the integral that you've written as a sum above.

The brackets at the stat mech page indicate a thermal average, which is an ensemble or time average over the 'experiment' taking place many times at many different states at some temperature.  This (the finite temperature) causes the fluctuations that give rise to the 'statistical' nature of the problem, and cause the decay of the correlation (loss of long range order).  This simply means that you should find the autocorrelation of several datasets, and average *those* together, but do not take the mean of the function.

As far as I can tell, your code is attempting to **weigh the correlation at `dt` by the length of the overlap length `dt`**, but I do not believe that this is correct.

With respect to the subtraction of `<s>`<sup>2</sup>, that's in the case of the spin model, where `<s>` would be the mean spin (magnetization), so I believe you are correct in that you should use `mean(x)**2`.

As a side-note, I would suggest using `mode='same'` instead of `'full'` so that the domain of your correlation matches the domain of your input without having to look at just one-half of the output (here the output is symmetric, so it doesn't really make a difference).

Comment: I disagree in the stat-mech bit. Of course from ergodicity we assume that the thermal average and the time average are equal. However, for calculating the latter you must consider the number of data-points. This means that the first equation would have to be normalized as ACF(dt) = 1./(T-dt)*sum_{t=0}^T [(x(t)*x(t+dt)]. This way we will be taking into consideration that for calculating the autocorrelation at long lags (large dt) the number of data-points is smaller than at short lags (small dt). Please check Equation (6.5) in Computer Simulation of Liquids (Allen & Tildesley, Oxford).

Comment: But you are correlating over time, no? Not averaging.  I don't believe you can assume ergodicity, but I don't know your system.  With ergodicity, the idea is that after averaging over a long time, you will explore the same states that you would if averaging over a large ensemble, but if you want to compare the system to itself as it changes over time, you're not averaging over time.  But it's possible that I'm very confused or misinterpreting you.  I do agree though with weighing by the number of data points.  (I have that book in my office, but will have to look at it at a later time)